# How to put SELECT inside CASE

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, case

I have a base and I need to display if object is ready to work after delivery status "Delivered"
And I need to put it inside function

```
DO
$$
BEGIN 
CASE
WHEN status IN ('In Transit','is going') THEN 'Not ready';
ELSE 'Ready';
end case;
end $$;
```

Table named Delivery and column status

Attempt with IF

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION prepare_object
()
RETURNS SETOF delivery
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS
$$
DECLARE answer varchar;
DECLARE status varchar;
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM delivery
            if status IN ('In Transit','is going');
                THEN answer = ('Not ready');
                ELSE answer = ('Ready');
            END IF;
    END;
    RETURN;
```

$$

Delivery table looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE Delivery
( 
Delivery_Code Serial PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,
Status varchar(255) CHECK (Status = 'Delivered' OR Status = 'In Transit' 
OR Status = 'is going'),
Composition_Delivery varchar(255),
Date_and_time timestamp,
Price money, 
Supplier_code Serial REFERENCES Provider(Supplier_code),
Request_Code Serial REFERENCES Request(Request_Code),
Object_ID serial REFERENCES Object(Object_ID)
);
```

Comment: Please read and follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: you have to many semicolons see the documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html+

Comment: Also: `DECLARE` starts a _block_ to declare variables. There is no need to  start a new block for each variable.

Comment: Are `status` and `answer` columns in your table? If yes, are you trying to convert the `status` value to a different value when selecting? Or should `answer` be a new expression in the SELECT list? If there is no such column in the `delivery` table, then you can't use `returns setof delivery` you need to use `returns table (...)` and specify each return column. But it sounds as if this can be achieved with a simple view as well.

Comment: I have column status, but I dont have column answer.

Comment: BEGIN
^if status IN ('In Transit','is going'); It shows me that I have syntax error here

Comment: If i delete second declare It gives me this error: DECLARE answer varchar^, status varchar;

Comment: So you want a result with the column `answer`?

Comment: Yes, I need table with column answer

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have a column expression `answer` there is no need for a function or PL/pgSQL. This can be achieved using a CASE expression in SQL:

```
SELECT d.*, 
       case 
         when d.status IN ('In Transit','is going') then 'Not ready'
         else 'Ready'
       end as answer
FROM delivery d
```

If you don't want to type this every time you retrieve rows from the table, put it into a VIEW.

Comment: It gives me syntax error on row "as answer"

Comment: @Hachaika: sorry, there was an `end` missing